# grails: many to many incorrect references

Tags: grails

being new to grails i've been following a youtube vid "getting started with grails part 1". now in the video you create a many to many reference of tags to tasks with the belongs to being the task.

these are my domains

```
package org.example.pomodoro
class Tag {
String name

static hasMany = [tasks: Task]
static belongsTo = Task

static constraints = {
    name blank:false, unique:true
}
String toString(){ return name}  
}
```

--

```
package org.example.pomodoro

class Task {    
String summary 
String details
Date dateCreated
Date deadline
Long timeSpent = 0L

static hasmany = [tags : Tag]   
static constraints = {
    summary blank:false , unique:true
    details blank:false, maxSize: 1000
    deadline nullable:true
    timeSpent min:0L 
}
}
```

my issue being that once running the app the links are added on the Tag and not the Task so you configure the tasks linked to the tags instead of the other way around. i have tried changing the belongsto but this dosnt change anything. Is there something possibly wrong with my code or that the guide im following is really old?

im using spring tools suite and grails 2.3.7

thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany). First line would make things clear.

Comment: i have tried configuring "static belongsTo = Tag" on the Task or "static belongsTo = Task" on the Tag but both result in the same thing of tasks being linked to tags. is this the wrong way of doing it?

Comment: Are you using scaffolding?

Comment: yes, "package org.example.pomodoro

class TagController {
static scaffold = Tag
}"   the same for the Task

Comment: *Grails' Scaffolding feature does not currently support many-to-many relationship and hence you must write the code to manage the relationship yourself* - Look for this warning message in the document link posted above.

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing it out, so the question remains. how did the guy in the video manage to do it with Scaffolding. or did he cheat some way ? in addition to, im nut too worried about managing it from both sides but i cant get it to be managed from the Task

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to create tasks and associate them with tags (or vice versa)?

Comment: as you can see above in the code, here are the extracts "static hasmany = [tags : Tag]   " from Task and "static hasMany = [tasks: Task]" from Tag